# Combine regex validation for pdf and file name should not have a '+' or '%' sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, validation

How to validate a filename with a extension '.pdf' and it should not have a '+' or '%' sign in its name? The regex to check for the 'pdf' extension is `/(\.|\/)(pdf)$/i,`. How to combine these validations?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
^[^+]+\.pdf$
```

- `^` - start of the string
- `[^+]+` - one or many characters except `+`

https://regex101.com/r/MZhqSL/4

Comment: smart solution, but be aware - the case insensitiv flag got lost